# Diagrams.net/Draw.io: Modifying the Mouse Over Hover Style for a Shape with Link?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

A published diagrams.net drawing is shown below.
Which contains a shape with a link assigned, with mouse-over (mouse-hover).
**Is it possible to change the mouse over outline styling, currently purple?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at the moment but feel free to vote/comment the feature request here: https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues/1633